Proving a claim in a proof of Riemann's Rearrangement Theorem presented in Analysis 1, by Terence Tao
As I'm working through Analysis 1 by Terence Tao, a claim to be proven by the reader in Theorem 8.2.8 has stopped me in my tracks.
In this question, the user Jose Antonio writes out the theorem and conjured up a proof for that claim (it's Claim 3 in his question), but I'm not too sure of its validity -- I honestly couldn't follow the logic. Is his proof for Claim 3 correct?
I tried to come up with my own proof, but a few things are getting in the way. First of all, Tao writes the claim as

The map $j \to n_j$ is surjective.

The way I started to prove this was to suppose, for sake of contradiction, there is a $n_{j}$ such that for all $j > i$, no such $j$ maps to $n_j$. But using this framework, I'm having difficulty to set up a contradiction, and I think it's because there's no explicit mapping I can work with. Without an explicit mapping to work with, how can I move on?
